# Is there a standard Windows library function to rotate 8bpp greyscale Bitmap by any angle?

Tags: .net, windows-xp

Is there a standard Windows library function which will rotate a 8bpp greyscale Bitmap by any angle, into another Bitmap?

Non-solutions discovered so far include 
1) Bitmap.RotateFlip (not any angle) 
2) Graphics.RotateTransform (not 8bpp)

Comment: You can't.  Convert it to a non-indexed color format first, then it is trivial.  Simply use the Bitmap(Image) constructor to convert.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that conversion's cost in CPU time and (since the only indexed formats are twice the size or more) memory. But it seems I have no choice. Thanks Hans. Please enter your repsonse as an answer so I may accept it.